# What is wrong with this analogy: Individuals are to alleles what governments are to individuals

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics

I'm an amateur when it comes to genetics, I'm hoping to learn something from the corrections. I am taking epigenetics into account (kind of); all 3 entities are susceptible to external physical influences.

Kind regards,

Frank

Comment: In this analogy, what is a gene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alleles are passed down (to individuals) and created by individuals (although not fully under their control). But individuals are not passed out or created by the governments (I suppose), although individuals are influenced by the governments and they can influence governments, whereas individuals can not necessarily influence the allele of the gene they already have unless you take epi-genetics into account. Also, the creation of an allele is not entirely influenced by individuals due to [independent assortment](http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/principle-of-independent-assortment-law-of-independent-302) and [chromosomal crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover), but individuals can more or less influence governments.